# Plotting multiple histograms in same panel

Tags: r, lattice

I am trying to plot multiple histograms of some variables in a data frame in the same panel. Here is some following code:

```
 library(lattice) 
 dd <- data.frame(gp = factor(rep(paste('Group', 1:6, sep = ''), each = 
 100)), x = rnorm(600)) 
 histogram( ~ x | gp, data = dd) 
 histogram( ~ x | gp, data = dd, as.table = TRUE)
```

This is putting the data x into the groups 1 to 6. In a given dataframe, we already have the numbers in particular categories. For example, suppose I want to plot a histogram of height, weight and average blood pressure (variables in a date frame) in the same panel. How would I do this without having to form a new data set and groups 1 to 3?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No need to reshape data here.

```
 histogram( ~ height +age +weight ,data = dd)
```

You can then ply with `layout` to change the display order of panels. For example:

```
 histogram( ~ height +age +weight ,layout=c(1,3),data = dd)
```

This will produce 3 histograms in 3 panels.

**EDIT**

to add a title you can use `main`

```
histogram( ~ height +age +weight ,layout=c(1,3),data = dd,
            main='PLEASE READ LATTICE HELP')
```

Side note: Settings parameters are shared between different lattice functions. For example the entry of xlab: `See xyplot`. when you go to xyplot help you can read :

```
main:
Typically a character string or expression describing the main 
       title to be placed on top of each page. Defaults to NULL
```

Comment: This is assuming that the column names are height, age and weight?

Comment: Is there anyway to add a title to the histogram?

Comment: Thanks. There wasn't an option for main in the histogram function in the help page.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be an answer to the original question, which asked how to put two histograms *in the same panel*.  Is that correct?  I have never seen `+` used in this way in a lattice plot, and I don't know what it means.  Without knowing what the data is supposed to look like, it's hard to test this proposal.  I created a dataframe using OP's method, but with a third column, and got strange results.